# Android speech input how to disable no matches found error

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm almost finished building an Android app that uses Speech recognition. Everything is working perfectly, except for...

Is there any way to disable the "No Matches found" error when the speech recognition dialog box is displayed? Or at least get the dialog box to close when an error like this occurs?

I'm trying to get speech from the user without the user having to press anything on the phone (which only happens during this dialog box - "no matches found" and "no speech heard" or whatever the error is!).

I've been searching for days but can't find an answer.

thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anyone else, where how to doto it:

[using speech](https://funwithdc.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/using-the-android-speech-recognition-apis/)

Check out his source at the bottom of his article.

Comment: excuse me where is the solution i cannot find it how to disable no_match errors